# Convert file object browser to buffer javascript

Tags: javascript, angularjs, file-upload, browser, buffer

How can I convert a file object uploaded to the browser to a buffer file?

For example the object from the image below:

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by a file uploaded to the browser? The browser uploads files to the server.

Comment: Javascript can't access the contents of local files. All it can do is send them to the server.